# Android trust specific domain certificate

Tags: android, ssl, dns, certificate, trust

I'm getting a error using httpclient: "No peer certificate"

So, I need configure the httpclient to trust all certificates from a specific domain, but  could not found a way to do this.

I don't want to allow all domains, just a specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to trust all certificates from a specific domain,...

That's not how trust works.
if you would trust just based on the domain name, then anybody could issue their own a certificate with your domain name and you would trust it.

You should instead make sure that you get a certificate which is

- is issued by a trusted CA
- is issued for the same hostname you use to access the site.

If the certificate fits these requirements no special validations are needed.

Comment: After check with analytics, I'm getting the error "No peer certificate" only at android 4.2.2.

Comment: Then you are probably using a CA which is not yet in the trust store or you might need to add certificates to the chain to verify correctly. Check your sie with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.lucasit.com) and look out for chain issues.

Comment: I tested with SSLLabs and get: Chain issues None

Comment: Check for alternative chains. If you need more help please publish the URL.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I cannot publish my client URL and they want change the CA... But here is the result from SSLLabs: http://s15.postimg.org/5ltxiqesb/ssllabs.jpg

Comment: @Isquierdo: look at trust path #2 and try to include this "extra download" certificate into your chain instead of the current chain certificate. Then the chain will lead to a root certificate which is much older and which is probably included in Android 4.2 already.

Comment: I don't really know how to include this extra download. This kind of SSL complications is not something I was expecting to deal with in this project. Can you explain how to include this, or send me some example? tks

Comment: This is a thing you have to do on the server side and how this is done depends on the server. There is usually lots of documentation on this topic on the internet. If in doubt ask at serverfault.com.  The certificate itself can probably be downloaded directly from the SSLLabs analysis.